# postgress-node error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm doing a simple request to a database and trying to retrieve all the table data. However, i get this error: *error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0*

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    //connection details
});

const query = async() => {
    await client.connect();
    const result = await client.query("SELECT * FROM asites", [1]);
    console.log(result.rows);
    client.end();
}

query();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After SELECT why do you have that part: ", [1]"?
This is probablty the error as you don't provide a bind in the statement.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I thought that I would access the results when data is retrieved from the server, as in ```client.query("SELECT * FROM asites", (req, res))```.